# setugid() error using matplotlib with apache and django

Tags: django, macos, apache, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib in a Django app served through apache on Mac OS X 10.7.5 but I can't get it to plot a figure for me. I've imported import `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, and the line in my view,

```
plt.plot(x, y)
```

(`x` and `y` are numpy arrays) is causing the error

```
2013-01-23 16:39:16.731 httpd[381:203] The application with bundle ID (null) is running setugid(), which is not allowed.
```

in my apache error_log. I'm afraid I don't know what `setugid()` is, or how to make running it allowed for my app.
My `$MPLCONFIGDIR` is set to `/tmp/.mplconfig` and apache as user _www has written a couple of empty directories to it, so that seems to be working OK.
Can anyone give me a clue?

Update: if I

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

and set up a figure, subplot and axes (the whole caboodle), I can savefig() without an error... what extra permissions does pyplot need?

Comment: More info [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/dns/entry/understanding_the_authorization_framework_on). Seems like a security setting on OS X is preventing it, and the quick fix seems to be to run apache as root.

Comment: Thanks for the reply tiago. Is running apache as root entirely wise, though?

Comment: In Linux/Unix apache usually is started as root but runs as user 'nobody'. I don't know in your particular case if it's wise or not.

Answer (score 3):

Using the agg backend after importing `matplotlib` got rid of the `setugid()` error in a `Flask app` running under `OS X Server` in `Sierra`

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.use('agg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add backend configuration globally for your system in `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` like:

```
backend: TkAgg
```

This will solve your problem as well. If you don't have `matplotlibrc`, just create one.